# sql query result with count istruction

Tags: mysql

I can't understand because this SQL query doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT Department, 
        IF(Department  = 'toys', COUNT(*), 0) AS nt, 
        IF(Department  = 'health', COUNT(*), 0) AS nh
FROM TABLE;
```

TABLE

```
Department  Value
toys        A
toys        B
toys        C
health      K
health      F
toys        G
toys        R
toys        W
toys        Q
```

I'd like to count number of occurrences about both toys record and health ones into 2 columns.

```
department    nt    nh
toys          7     0
health        0     2
```

WHY ?!

thanks

Comment: Have a look at other instances where a COUNT function is used. Copy them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT department,
       SUM(IF(Department  = 'toys',1 , 0)) AS nt, 
       SUM(IF(Department  = 'health', 1, 0)) AS nh
FROM TABLE;
```

This will get you count in two columns.

If it will match it will return only one sum that.

Alternate query which i would like to recommend

```
SELECT Department, 
       COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE Department IN ('toys','health')
GROUP BY Department;
```

This query will give you department wise count.

Comment: But that will give him only one department.

Comment: `COUNT(1)` seams to be a dark days SQL optimisation trick? Nowadays this is not needed annymore..

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional `group by`, something like :

```
select 
Department,
count(case when Department = 'toys' then 1 end) as nt,
count(case when Department = 'health' then 1 end) as nh    
from t
group by Department
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySql it's easy to write such conditional aggregate expressions when grouping, like:

```
select
  Department, 
  sum(Department = 'toys') nt,
  sum(Department = 'health') nh
from tablename
group by Department
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gXePFmubLwBRrW5mTPSMQz/0).
Results:

```
| Department | nt  | nh  |
| ---------- | --- | --- |
| toys       | 7   | 0   |
| health     | 0   | 2   |
```